# ProcessOptions and ProcessKeyvalOptions

Tags: documentclass-writing, options, class-options, kvoptions

## `\ProcessOptions` and `\ProcessKeyvalOptions`

Which comes first? Does it matter?

## `\ProcessOptions\relax` or `\ProcessOptions*`

What's the difference? Apparently for keyval there is only the starred version. Which should I use? I looked at the docs and they were not extremely helpful.

---

*I'm creating my own class based on `article`. I'm using `kvoptions` for the easy creation of boolean options (`\DeclareBoolOption` and `\DeclareComplementaryOption`).*

Answer (score 17):

### Without package `kvoptions`

An option is defined by

```
\DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>}
```

The star form defines the behavior for unknown options:

```
\DeclareOption*{<code>}
```

Options are processed by

```
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

that processes the options in the order of declaration in the package file
(seldom useful) or

```
\ProcessOptions*
```

that process the options in calling order (usually recommended).

### With package `kvoptions`

With package `kvoptions` the replacement for `\ProcessOptions*`
is `\ProcessKeyvalOptions`. Neither `\ProcessOptions` nor `\ProcessOptions*` should be used together with `\ProcessKeyvalOptions`.

Package options are now interpreted as key value options.
They can be defined with `\define@key` of package `keyval`. But package `kvoptions`
provides some shortcuts: `\DeclareBoolOption`, `\DeclareStringOption`, ...

`\DeclareOption` is replaced by `\DeclareVoidOption` and `\DeclareOption*` is replaced by `\DeclareDefaultOption`.

For a more complete example, see [section "3 Example" of package `kvoptions`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvoptions.pdf).

Comment: I'd still be curious why almost all examples add \relax after \ProcessOptions, even though this is supposed to be a no-op?

Comment: @FlorianEchtler The syntax of `\ProcessOptions` knows an optional star. The `\relax` acts as stopper that the command is finished and no optional star is following.

Answer (score 5):

Testing this on examples, the order of `\ProcessOptions` and `\ProcessKeyvalOptions` does not seem to matter, unless of course the code of one set options directly affects that of the other.

For `\ProcessOptions\relax` vs. `\ProcessOptions*`, [clsguide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide) explains that the order the options is processed in is different:

> `\ProcessOptions*`:
>   This is like `\ProcessOptions` but it
>   executes the options in the order specified in the calling commands,
>   rather than in the order of declaration in the class or package. For a
>   package this means that the global options are processed first.

As to which you should use, if you are writing the class completely from scratch, **I would advise that you use just one style; either use `kvoptions` for all of your own options or use exclusively the classical style**.  If your are building your class on top of an existing one, then it depends on the details: if you are only adding new options then `\LoadClassWithOptions` may well be sufficient to deal with the old options of that class and you can stick to the `kvoptions` style for your own additions.