# Option seemingly ignored

Tags: fontsize, article, class-options, options

I'm trying to give my custom class file two options for font size, `11pt` and `12pt`. I want `12pt` to be the default. I create the options like this:

```
\DeclareOption{11pt}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{article}}

\DeclareOption{12pt}{
    \PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}}

\ExecuteOptions{12pt}
\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass[]{article}
```

This works fine, the default font size becomes 12pt. However the problem occurs when in the case that I want to go against this default and use 11pt font, using, of course, the `11pt` option like so:

```
\documentclass[11pt]
```

This does nothing when it should change the font size to 11pt (actually 10.95pt, since that is what the `article` class uses as a substitute for 11pt, but this does not matter). How can I make the `11pt` option override the default `12pt`? I can't seem to figure it out, Is it simply a problem with my method?

Interestingly enough, if I make `11pt` the default option, with `\ExecuteOptions{11pt}`, then I can use `\documentclass[12pt]` and get `12pt` font, but just not the other way around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also `\documentclass[12pt,11pt]{article}` uses 12pt and the 11pt option has no effect. Here's a workaround

```
\ProvidesClass{akuritsu}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\aku@ptsize{2}}

\ExecuteOptions{12pt}
\ProcessOptions
\PassOptionsToClass{1\aku@ptsize pt}{article}

\LoadClass{article}
```

In this way only one font size option is passed.

Comment: That looks good, so are you saying that my problem is that `article` is passed both `12pt` and `11pt` as options?

Comment: @akuritsu Yes, that's the problem

Comment: Thank you, although I didn't use your workaround, your answer (and comment) solved the problem.

Comment: Doesn't this always pass `12pt` to `article`, since `12pt` is always executed and the last declared option?

Comment: With `\ProcessOptions*` instead of `\ProcessOptions` the code would be correct, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82441/115883).

Comment: @John Did you test? I did (also a minute ago for safety) and it works exactly as advertised.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. If I use the class and write `\makeatletter\aku@ptsize\makeatother`, it gives always a 2, even when I use the options like this: `\documentclass[12pt,11pt]{akuritsu}`. Although you did not explicitly mention in your answer, that the class options will be processed in the order they have been specified, I though this is what you mean by "workaround", since you showed the problem with `article` right before.

Comment: @John Why would you specify both options?

Comment: @egreg: I have a build script for exercise sheets to compile them as `exercises`, `hints` and `solutions` with class options. In the build script there is a regular expression used in `sed` that adds the desired class option as last option (maybe adding `[,` before and `]` after). It is simpler to just add it, without having to remove maybe existing class options. BTW, this is the command: `sed -E "s/(documentclass[^[{]*)(\[)?([^]{]*)(\])?(.+)/\1[\3,${classoption}]\5/" "$file"`

Comment: Sorry for commenting several years later. When I try using ``\PassOptionsToClass`` inside ``\DeclareOption`` as well as outside after ``ProcessOptions`` as you did in your answer, the default option is passed to the class. Any idea? By reading your answer and the comments, it seems that the``\PassOptionsToClass`` outside everything should be the first one passing the option.